# Why is the torsion subgroup of the Neron Severi group a birational invariant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$, $NS(X)$ be its Neron-Severi group, i.e., the abelian group generated by divisors modulo algebraic equivalence, and $NS_{tor}(X)$ be the torsion subgroup of $NS(X)$. Could anyone help me to understand why is $NS(X)$ a birational invarint?

Comment: Check how $NS(X)$ changes under a smooth blowup, and then use Weak Factorization theorem.

Comment: Ah, I should have realized. Thank you!